# Simple IEqualityComparer<T> question

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove duplicate entries from a list which contains a generic object.

```
public class MessageInfo
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class SMSDupeRemover : IEqualityComparer<MessageInfo>
{
    public bool Equals(MessageInfo x, MessageInfo y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MessageInfo obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the code to remove the dupes:

```
IEnumerable<MessageInfo> new_texts = text_messages.Distinct(new SMSDupeRemover());
```

The problem is Equals and GetHashCode is never called. Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `Distinct` is lazy. Try to add `ToList()` at the end.

Longer answer. Linq operations are actually declarative ones. They define query, but they do not tell to execute it. `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't contain data, just query definition. You have constructed query, okay, how to get data?

- `foreach` the `IEnumerable`. Since `foreach` is imperative all data must be retrieved (query executed).
- Call `ToList`/`ToDictionary`. Those collections store real data so in order to populate them system has to execute query.

Comment: Perfect, I understand now. It was driving me crazy... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is lazily evaluated, so that won't execute until you call `GetEnumerator` and possibly even `MoveNext`.

Try adding a `.ToList()` to the end of that query and it should execute right away.

Answer (score 2):

The IEqualityComparer isn't called until the IEnumerable is enumerated.

Try

```
var new_texts = text_messages.Distinct(new SMSDupeRemover()).ToList();
```

Comment: Oooh, I had no idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
List<MessageInfo> unique_msgs = 
    new List(text_messages.Distinct(new SMSDupeRemover()));
```

to immediately render the new list.  Unless you really need enumerator, to conserve the memory.